# what happens internally when we declared static method or any field in class?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Please tell what happens internally when we declares the static method or any static field in 
class .
why static members only accessed by class name not by instance of class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A static member is not associated with a class instance.
Rather, it's associated with the class itself, and it only exists in one place.
Therefore, it doesn't make sense to call it on a specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

a static class cannot be instantiated. In other words, you cannot use the new keyword to create a variable of the class type. Because there is no instance variable, you access the members of a static class by using the class name itself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx